# Two ListViews in the same column - Vertical viewport was given unbounded height

Tags: flutter

This widget render as expected

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('text'),),
  body: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true, // should it be here?
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(
            title: Row(
              children: const <Widget>[
                Expanded(child: Text('text'),),
                Expanded(child: Text('text'),),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      // RapportList(), - the issue arises when I uncomment this
    ],
  ),
);
```

The issue arises when I uncomment `RapportList()`. It is statefull widget which builds:

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: _rapports.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
        ...
```

So if I uncommnet that line then I get a lot of errors

> The following assertion was thrown during performResize(): Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.
>
> Viewports expand in the scrolling direction to fill their container.
>   In this case, a vertical viewport was given an unlimited amount of
>   vertical space in which to expand. This situation typically happens
>   when a scrollable widget is nested inside another scrollable widget.
>
> If this widget is always nested in a scrollable widget there is no
>   need to use a viewport because there will always be enough vertical
>   space for the children. In this case, consider using a Column instead.
>   Otherwise, consider using the "shrinkWrap" property (or a
>   ShrinkWrappingViewport) to size the height of the viewport to the sum
>   of the heights of its children.
>
> The relevant error-causing widget was:    ListView
>   file:///C:/Users/andre/AndroidStudioProjects/rapport_help/lib/rappport_list.dart:147:21
>   When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
>   0      RenderViewport.performResize. (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1172:15)
>
> 1      RenderViewport.performResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1233:6)
>
> 2      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1703:9)
>
> 3      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
>
> 4      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7) ... The following
>
> RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired:
>   RenderViewport#8c103 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
>   NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE ...  needs compositing ...  parentData:
>    (can use size) ...  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=360.0,
>   0.0<=h<=Infinity) ...  size: MISSING ...  axisDirection: down ...  crossAxisDirection: right ...  offset:
>   ScrollPositionWithSingleContext#d6e6c(offset: 0.0, range: null..null,
>   viewport: null, ScrollableState, AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics ->
>   ClampingScrollPhysics, IdleScrollActivity#96b7b, ScrollDirection.idle)
>   ...  anchor: 0.0 RenderObject: RenderViewport#8c103 NEEDS-LAYOUT
>   NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

And by alone the `RapportList()` renders with no issues, so why they can not be in the same column?

Comment: I closed this question, if you think this wasn't a duplicate, let me know, I'll be happy to reopen it.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad thanks buddy, actually that answer solws it partly but I was able to make it

Comment: Glad to hear it :)

Comment: @CopsOnRoad there is another issue arised. now it is not scrollable even after I added `scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,`. I'll open new question then.